# Maven Error While updating Dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a maven project in which i am getting the following error. I am using eclipse IDE

```
     An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects".
     Unsupported IClasspathEntry kind=4
```

Comment: 1. The error is Eclipse-specific (tagged it as such). 2. **If you have found a solution, you should post it as an answer**, not within the question.

Comment: I thought to share the solution for the problem which i faced. So i posted it and i actually not getting to know how to post it as answer directly. can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: That's excellent, in fact self-answered questions [are encouraged here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to) :). In this particular case you need to 1. Copy the "answer part" of your text into an actual answer (there should be a "Your Answer" box below these comments). 2. After you post the answer, remove the "answer part" out of your question. 3. After the grace period ends, accept your answer, if there are no better ones posted by others of course.

Comment: Thank you. Also please answer this question, if you have any idea "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144585/spring-security-multiple-authentication-filters"

Comment: That's about right. I've taken the liberty to make minor stylistic improvements. Regarding the other question - sorry, can't help you there, not much experience with Spring I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed below steps for resolving this error. The reason for this error is class path file located in your project folder.

1. Disable Maven Nature for your project ( If in eclipse, right click on the `project --> Maven --> Disable Maven Nature`).
2. Delete the class path file in your project folder.
3. Re- enable the Maven Nature Again (right click on `project --> configure --> Convert to Maven Project`).
4. Try to Maven clean, install and Run the project.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better answer:  stop using eclipse.

Here's the eclipse bug page: 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=394042

They seem to have no interest in fixing this issue, so if you require|prefer to use the command line for projects, then really there is no fix but to quit eclipse.