# Spring Security Multiple Authentication Filters

Tags: spring, spring-security

In my project i have declared two authentication filters as mentioned below in spring-security-context.xml file

```
    <beans:bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <sec:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="authenticationProcessingFilterWithDB, authenticationProcessingFilterWithXML" />
    </sec:filter-chain-map>
    </beans:bean>
```

I have declared authentication manager for each filter in following way:

```
<beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilterWithDB" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManagerWithDB" />
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check_with_db" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilterWithXML" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManagerWithXML" />
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check_with_xml" />
</beans:bean>
```

but when i try to access /j_spring_security_check_with_xml from jsp then it is giving resource not found error. The same is working if give default '/j_spring_security_check' with single authentication manager. Please give the solution for adding multiple authentication manager in spring security as i should be able to verify login details against xml file (where username and password will be provided),against Data base

Comment: You don't need duplicate filters. You can simply specify a single `AuthenticationManager` with multiple providers. All the providers will be called until authentication is done. Basically your setup is to complex.

Comment: No. What i want is different. To say briefly, i will be having combo box in jsp page to select which type of authentication. If i selected xml authentication then i need to authenticate only against xml file but not against Database